# ggplot2 geom_smooth independently of variable shape and colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to get a ggplot with a single and common geom smooth for all variables, independently of shape and colour.
    I tried to force the colour as "red" with no success.
    My script goes like this:

```
 ggplot(CRESCITA, aes(DAGE,PESO, shape=PEN,col=RPRO))
 + geom_point(size=4) + xlim(250,600) + geom_hline(yintercept = 400)
 + geom_vline(xintercept = 380) +  geom_smooth(method = lm , col="red")
```

And that's what I got.
[image: that's]

It doesn't look bad at all, but how to get only one `geom_smooth` for all the points included in the `ggplot`? Thanks and kind regards!!!

Comment: Please provide example data so that others can run your code. Looking at `group=1` in ggplot should address your question.

Comment: move `shape` and `col` to the `geom_point` call: `ggplot(CRESCITA, aes(DAGE,PESO)) + 
  geom_point(size=4, aes(shape=PEN,col=RPRO)) + xlim(250,600) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 400) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 380) +  
  geom_smooth(method = lm , col="red")`

Comment: Great!!!! It works. Many thanks bouncyball.

Comment: I am sorry; I am new in this and I don't know how to provide example data. I'll try. Thanks again.